# p:calendar not poping up

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I know it's been asked several times but I didn't find the solution. I am trying to use `p:calendar` but it is not popping up, just the text field is showing. Other components are working fine. I am using PrimeFaces 5.3 and mojarra 2.2. Also I am using jsf templating. I tried adding to main template file as well as the `<h:head>` tag in this view. Calendar is shown in dialog component. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewAction actionListener="#{providerController.onLoad()}" />
        </f:metadata>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/Views/Template/MainTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="pageTitle">
            Welcome [Dashboard.xhtml]
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="mainContent">
            <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>

                <h2>Provider Details</h2>
 <p:calendar id="cal"  showOn="button" />
                <h:form rendered="#{providerController.canCreateProvider()}">
                    <p:commandButton value="Create" update=":myForm"
                        action="#{providerController.createProviderClicked()}"
                        oncomplete="PF('Dlg1').show();" />
                    <br />
                </h:form>

                <h:form id="mainForm">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{providerController.providerList}"
                        var="provider">

<!--    <p:inputText value="#{providerController.providerSearchText}">
                        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{providerController.providerSearchTextChanged()}"></f:ajax>
                        </p:inputText> -->
                        <p:column headerText="Provider Name" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{provider.getFullName()}">

                            #{provider.getFullName()}
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Npi Number">
                            #{provider.npiNum}
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Entity">
                            #{provider.centity.name}
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Practices">
                            <table>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{provider.practiceList.toArray()}" var="t">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border: 0px;"><h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </table>

                            <!--                     <p:selectOneMenu id="advanced"
                                 panelStyle="width:180px"
                                effect="fade" var="t" style="width:160px">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{provider.practiceList.toArray()}" var="practise"
                                    itemLabel="#{practise.name}" itemValue="#{practise}" />

                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                                </p:column>

                            </p:selectOneMenu>  -->
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Edit" width="80"
                            rendered="#{providerController.canEditProvider()}">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":myForm"
                                oncomplete="PF('Dlg1').show();"
                                action="#{providerController.updateClicked(provider)}" />

                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" update=":mainForm"
                                resetValues="true"
                                action="#{providerController.removeClicked(provider)}"
                                rendered="#{providerController.shouldShowDelete()}">

                                <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"
                                    icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                                hideEffect="fade">
                                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                            </p:confirmDialog>

                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>

                <!-- ADD / EDIT DIALOG -->

                <p:dialog id="providerDialog" header="Provider" modal="true"
                    position="top" widgetVar="Dlg1" minHeight="40">

                    <h:form id="myForm">
                        <p:messages id="msgs" />

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="8">
                            <p:outputLabel id="entity"
                                value="#{providerController.getFirstEntityName()}"
                                rendered="#{providerController.isSingleItemInEntityList()}" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="entities"
                                value="#{providerController.currentEntity}"
                                panelStyle="width:180px" effect="fade" required="true"
                                style="width:177px"
                                rendered="#{!providerController.isSingleItemInEntityList()}"
                                disabled="#{providerController.getIsEntityListDisabled()}">

                                <p:ajax listener="#{providerController.onEntityChange}"
                                    update="myPractices" />

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Entity" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{providerController.entityList}"
                                    var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.name}"
                                    itemValue="#{entity.getId()}" />

                                <!-- <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                                </p:column> -->
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="myPractices"
                                value="#{providerController.selectedPractices}"
                                label="Select Practices" filter="true"
                                filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="width:177px" var="t"
                                panelStyle="width:250px">

                                <f:selectItems value="#{providerController.practiceList}"
                                    var="practice" itemLabel="#{practice.name}"
                                    itemValue="#{practice.getId()}" />

                                <!-- <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                                </p:column> -->

                            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

                            <!-- <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{providerController.selectedPayers}" label="Select Payers"
                            filter="false" filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="width:177px"  var="t" required="true"
                            converter="payerConverter" panelStyle="width:250px">

                            <f:selectItems value="#{providerController.payerList}" var="payer"
                                itemLabel="#{payer.name} #{payer.planName}" itemValue="#{payer}"  />

                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
                            </p:column>

                        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>  -->

                            <p:inputText id="NpiNumber"
                                value="#{providerController.provider.npiNum}"
                                placeholder="Npi Number" maxlength="10" label="NPI"
                                required="true"
                                validatorMessage="NPI should only digits and length 10">
                                <!--  validator="npiValidator" -->
                                <f:validateRegex for="NpiNumber" pattern="[0-9]{10}" />
                                <!-- <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/> -->

                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:inputText value="#{providerController.provider.firstName}"
                                placeholder="First Name" label="FirstName" required="true" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{providerController.provider.lastName}"
                                placeholder="Last Name" label="Last Name" required="true" />

                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <br />
                        <h:dataTable id="filesTable"
                            value="#{providerController.documentCells}" var="docCell">

                            <p:column>
                            <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{docCell.document.effectiveDate}" showOn="button" />
                                <p:row style="border: 3px solid blue;">
                                    <b><h:outputLabel for="fileUpload"
                                            value="#{docCell.lbName}" styleClass="#{docCell.getColorClassName()}" /></b>
                                    <br />

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Existing File: " for="idFileName" styleClass="#{docCell.getColorClassName()}" />
                                    <h:outputLabel id="idFileName"
                                        value="#{docCell.document.orignalName}" styleClass="#{docCell.getColorClassName()}" />
                                    <br />
                                    <p:fileUpload value="#{docCell.document.orignalName}"
                                        fileUploadListener="#{providerController.handleFileUpload}"
                                        mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" fileLimit="3"
                                        sizeLimit="5242880" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|doc?x|png|txt)$/"
                                        update=":myForm" label="Browse..." 
                                        >

                                        <f:attribute name="name" value="#{docCell}" />

                                    </p:fileUpload>
                                </p:row>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Remove">

                                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                    action="#{providerController.deleteFileClicked(docCell)}"
                                    update=":myForm">

                                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"
                                        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                                </p:commandButton>

                                <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                                    hideEffect="fade">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                                        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                                    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                                        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                                </p:confirmDialog>

                            </p:column>


                        </h:dataTable>

                        <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" validateClient="true"
                            actionListener="#{providerController.saveInfo}"
                            update="msgs, :mainForm" />




                        <p:blockUI trigger="myForm:btnSave" block="providerDialog">
            LOADING<br />
                            <p:graphicImage value="/Images/loading.gif" width="75"
                                height="75" />
                        </p:blockUI>
                    </h:form>


                </p:dialog>


                <style>
#providerDialog {
    position: absolute !important;
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:green}
</style>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too much code, try to narrow the problem. [mcve]

Comment: If you use technology, please make sure you write the names correctly (PrimeFaces, Mojarra). If you make the same mistakes in search engines, you might not get good hits. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info to

Comment: Afaik you should'nt include jquery manually, it will be injected to h:head

Answer (score 0):

Try put your `p:calendar` component into `h:form`. It is outside of them.

Comment: or it is in a nested form!